# Initialize Class with Generic Types in Another AppDomain

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am trying to setup a tool I can use to load non-version-specific assemblies from a config/database/etc. at runtime, execute code as needed, and then unload them to eliminate overhead. (My situation has many possible alternate code flows, and I'd like to not force a recompile of the entire app to onboard or edit a single flow)

I've setup a library to run AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap to initialize classes in separate AppDomains, but as far as I can tell from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createinstancefromandunwrap?view=netframework-4.0), this doesn't support generic type arguments on the class.

How can I initialize classes with type arguments in a different AppDomain than the executing code from a type name and assembly path? If that's not possible, is there any way to load assemblies in a different AppDomain than the executing code such that it handles dependencies automatically the same way that AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap does (assuming I could then find a way to call Type.MakeGenericType that executes in the temporary AppDomain from the original AppDomain)?

Comment: You sure about this : `but as far as I can tell, this doesn't support generic type arguments on the class.`? Can you show us how you tried that and what error you get after.

Comment: Are you aware that creating additional AppDomains is not supported on .NET Core and .NET 5+, and there are [no plans on adding it in the future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#application-domains), leaving you stuck on .NET Framework?

Comment: @Eldar I updated the post to include a link to the documentation I was reviewing which doesn't contain an overflow for type arguments

Comment: Maybe you can put your own method into the AppDomain, pass it the generic type and its type arguments, and let it bootstrap the process.

Comment: @madreflection I became aware of this after starting the project, but it sounds like I'll be able to unload assemblies through AssemblyLoadContext in .net core, and unloading is the only reason I'm using AppDomains at all

Comment: You should be able to get the assembly qualified name easily for any type - it's just `type.AssemblyQualifiedName`. That's what `AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` wants as the second parameter.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'll know anything necessary about the assembly/type at runtime. The issue is that the only way I can figure to initialize a class with type arguments in a different appdomain is to maintain a library to do so with an array of types, but then I would have to use AppDomain.Load (unless I'm mistaken) to load EVERY dependent assembly in order from config items... I'd like to avoid having to hand-hold the app that much